# Having list of keys, get list/tuple of values from dict

Tags: python, dictionary, key

Is there an easy, readable and Pythonic way of extracting particular values from dict when I have list of keys?

I often find myself doing things like this:

```
uri = "http://%s:%s" % (self.options['listener_port'], self.options['listener_host'])
```

which is ugly and long.  I always feel that writing something like:

```
uri = "http://%s:%s" % self.options['listener_port', 'listener_host']
```

should be possible but it's not valid (at least not in Python 2.7).

What's the "official" Pythonic way?

Comment: something like `[mydict[k] for k in list_of_keys]`, you mean? Or in your case, `[self.options[k] for k in ['listener_port', 'listener_host']`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) instead of (more old-fashioned) `%` formatting, you can simply do:

```
"http://{0[listener_port]}:{0[listener_host]}".format(self.options)
```

---

In the more general case, you can get multiple values from a `dict` from a list of `keys` like:

```
values = [d[key] for key in keys]
```

and unpack using `*`, e.g.

```
"http://{0}:{1}".format(*(d[key] for key in keys))
```

but you *can't* unpack to `%` formatting.

Comment: Nice but it does not really get list/tuple of values from the dict.

Comment: @AloisMahdal I have updated with some more general info