# How do I retrieve more than one item pair from a dictionary

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary

Does anyone know how I retrieve two pairs from a dictionary 
I'm trying to present data in a more compact format

```
a = {1:'item 1', 2:'item 2', 3:'item 3', 4:'item 4' }
for i,j,k,l in a:
    print i, ' - ' ,j , ' , ' ,k, ' - ' ,l
```

> 1 - item 1 , 2 - item 2
>
> 3 - item 3 , 4 - item 4

edit - sorry ment it to look like above

Comment: possible duplicate of [Having list of keys, get list/tuple of values from dict](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23156853/having-list-of-keys-get-list-tuple-of-values-from-dict)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `iter()` to convert the sorted items to an iterator, and then loop over that iterator to get the pairs.

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> items =  iter(sorted(a.items())) #As dicts are unordered
>>> print ' '.join('{} - {} , {} - {}'.format(*chain(x, next(items))) for x in items)
1 - item 1 , 2 - item 2 3 - item 3 , 4 - item 4
```

Another way to get the pairs is to use the [`zip(*[iter(seq)]*n)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233204/how-does-zipitersn-work-in-python) trick:

```
>>> items = sorted(a.items())
>>> grouped = zip(*[iter(items)]*2)
>>> print ' '.join('{} - {} , {} - {}'.format(*chain(*x)) for x in grouped)
1 - item 1 , 2 - item 2 3 - item 3 , 4 - item 4
```

Comment: Again, my apologies! - I had not represented the output how I truly wanted it. Your method worked perfectly to produce what I originally asked for. Cheers

Comment: @FloggedHorse This should do it: `for x in grouped: print '{} - {} , {} - {}'.format(*chain(*x))`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want:

```
a = {1:'item 1', 2:'item 2', 3:'item 3', 4:'item 4' }

for i,j in a.items():
    print i, ' - ' ,j, ',',

[OUTPUT]
1 - item 1 , 2 - item 2 , 3 - item 3 , 4 - item 4 ,
```

**Or even more simply**

```
l = [' - '.join(map(str, i)) for i in a.items()]

>>> print l
1 - item 1, 2 - item 2, 3 - item 3, 4 - item 4
```

Comment: @Aशwiniचhaudhary, Could please explain my mistake? Thank you

Comment: Compare this `1 - item 1 , 2 - item 2 3 - item 3 , 4 - item 4` to your output.

Comment: @Aशwiniचhaudhary, Do you mean my extra `,` between 2 and 3?

Comment: Sorry my mistake! It did what I asked for, but I asked for the wrong thing :( - Ive edited the output to how I wanted it. Your example is all dependent upon the comma at the end of the print statement.- cheers